# How to run the drools examples on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, x11, drools

I am just getting started with Drools and on a linux EC2 instance and trying to run the examples: runExamples.sh  but it needs an X11 display. So how do I configure this to display from the instance to my windows laptop, or run the examples script in command line mode? Or is there another simpler example that I can run to get started?

Comment: the question is why do you want to run the examples with UI in amazon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the X-server of another node in a network by

```
$ export DISPLAY=<hostname>:0.0
```

Replace `<hostname>` with the host name when it is known to the localhost (add this to /etc/hosts) ir the IP address.